# illogical output from SQL statement with IN command

Tags: sql, sqlite

Why does this code output the names of countries with populations less than `25000000`?

```
SELECT name, continent, population 
FROM world x  
WHERE continent IN(SELECT continent FROM world
WHERE population >= 25000000)
```

I am practicing on SQLZOO. https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial and use firefox(SQLite)

Here's the output.
[output of SQL Code with IN statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKkJi.png)

Comment: Please edit your post with the actual text of the query you're using, and a sample of the data. It is preferred rather than posting links to images.

Comment: @mechanical_meat There is link to the test sandbox for this example.

Comment: @mechanical_meat, Hi. This is my first question so I don't have enough points to paste images directly.

Answer (score 0):

Subquery selectes **continents** which consist of countries with population bigger than 2500000.

```
SELECT continent FROM world
WHERE population >= 25000000
```

Your final query returns countries which lay in continents from first subquery (with condition `WHERE continent IN (first subquery)`, so it doesn't even check population of these countries.

```
SELECT name, continent, population 
FROM world x  
WHERE continent IN (SELECT continent FROM world
WHERE population >= 25000000)
```